# Does electroplating fall off if I disconnect electrolytic cell?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, electroplating

So I understand the basic mechanism of electroplating. I want to ask is there any chance that the electroplating may fall off if I disconnect the electricity supply? As a consequence, should I recommend the plated object to be taken out of the electrolytic solution before disconnecting the electricity supply?

Specifically I want to know if disconnecting electrolytic cell can be the sole reason why the plating on an electrode may fall off.

Comment: If the plating falls off when the power is cut in solution, then it would fall off after being taken out of solution as well.

Comment: @JonCuster Does it actually ever fall off?That's my question...

Comment: Electroplating can - bad surface prep, too high of a stress built up, etc. Just like any other coating.

Comment: @JonCuster Assuming I have done everything properly... can the electroplating fall off only due to disconnection of electrolytic cell?

Comment: No.$\mathstrut$